# Postgres query which runs itself after every 1 hour

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dbeaver

I am using Postgres with the Dbeaver tool. Dbeaver invalidates a connection after some time period and when a query is being fired after a long period of time, it takes a bit longer to execute.

I need to write a query that kind of runs itself after every 1 hour and executes a query to any table in the database so that my connection does not go to the idle phase.

Task scheduler is available in Dbeaver EE which does this job, but as I am using its community edition I was thinking of doing it the way explained above.

I tried writing the below query. It has a loop and inside the loop, I was trying to hold the query execution using pg_sleep but that doesn't work. It gives me the below error. In addition, I was thinking to run this loop infinitely.

Can you please help?

```
do $$
declare 
   counter integer := 0;
begin
   while counter < 24 loop --need to change it to infinite loop
    pg_sleep(3600);   --wait for 1 hour
    perform 'select * from user_roles ur';  --any query to run
    counter := counter + 1;
   end loop;
end$$;
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "pg_sleep"
```

Comment: Don't do that. Instead, use a tool that is less broken.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use `cron` on linux or `windows task scheduler` on windows ,
or you could use `pgagent` which comes with `pgadmin`.

however in your query you need to `select sleep(second)` :

```
do $$
declare 
   counter integer := 0;
begin
   while counter < 24 loop --need to change it to infinite loop
    select pg_sleep(3600);   --wait for 1 hour
    perform 'select * from a_files af ';  --any query to run
    counter := counter + 1;
   end loop;
end$$;
```